# Use file in directory as argument but without the extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I have a file called "data1.dat", I want to be able to use the file as an argument in my script without the .dat extension:

```
./myscript.sh data1
```

instead of

```
./myscript.sh data1.dat
```

is this possible, if so how would you do it?

Comment: In your script, after your sanity checks, something like `myfile=${1}.dat`, followed by references to `$myfile`?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. You'll just need to do some text-processing of the input given--if it doesn't already end in `.dat`, you just add the `.dat`.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <datafile name>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

DATFILE="$1"

if [[ "$DATFILE" != *".dat" ]]; then
    DATFILE="${DATFILE}.dat"
fi

if [[ ! -r "$DATFILE" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Data file '${DATFILE}' does not exist." >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Using data file '${DATFILE}'..."
```

Answer (score 1):

assumming extension is always .dat

```
filedat=$(dirname -- "$1")/$(basename -- "$1" .dat).dat
```

where

- `$1` is argument
- `$(dirname -- "$1")` will pick dir name `(dirname ../foo/bar/baz.dat )` => `../foo/bar`
- `$(basename -- "$1" .dat)` will trip optional .dat `$(basename foo.dat .dat)` => `foo`, `$(basename foo .dat)` => `foo`